# Can MPlayer flip a video horizontally?

Tags: video, video-player, mplayer, playback

I know VLC can do it but that stopped working :(

Can Gnome MPV do it? Can MPlayer do it?

It makes learning Tai Chi from videos soo much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking you are after the 'mirror' function of MPlayer and perhaps the easiest way to accomplish this is by using the excellent MPlayer gui: SMPlayer.

Simply follow this trail after opening SMPlayer:

```
Video --> Mirror_image
```

to flip the video 180% horizontally, or more correctly: 'mirror'! Screenshot below on my own system:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the command line, the option you are looking for is `-vf mirror`

So to view a video file mirrored, you might use:

```
mplayer myfile.mp4 -vf mirror
```

Answer (score 0):

For `mpv`, the `-vf mirror` option from `mplayer` isn't supported. The mpv documentation claims that `--vf=hflip` should work, but I get the error

```
[ffmpeg] Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter
'mpv_src_default_in' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[lavfi] failed to configure the filter graph
Disabling filter hflip.00 because it has failed.
```

What actually worked for me is `mpv --lavfi-complex='[vid1] hflip [vo]' file.mp4`

Comment: Perhaps simpler to use FFplay: `ffplay -vf "hflip" -i file.mp4` ? And just as a btw the command `mpv -vf=hflip file.mp4` works fine on my system...